# GTK3: How can I disable default widget activation?

Tags: gtk3, gtk#

Here's a sample GTK# program that listens for key presses and prints them.

```cs
using Gtk;
using Application = Gtk.Application;

Application.Init();

Window win = new Window("Title");
win.DeleteEvent += (_, eventArgs) => Application.Quit();
win.KeyPressEvent += (_, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key down {eventArgs.Event.Key}");
};
win.KeyReleaseEvent += (_, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key up   {eventArgs.Event.Key}");
};

win.Show();

Application.Run();
```

I would expect to see <kbd>Enter</kbd> key presses, but I don't. Instead, they are mapped to activate the window's default widget. Can I disable this functionality so that <kbd>Enter</kbd> key presses are also caught by the key listener?

Comment: Have you tried adding the KeyPressEvent mask to the window? I.e. Events |= Gdk.EventMask.KeyPressMask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK comes with a set of default keybinds, maintained by a `GtkBindingSet` (C name). In C, one would essentially do:

```c
GtkBindingSet* binding_set = gtk_binding_set_by_class(GTK_TYPE_WINDOW);
// For each keybinding that needs removal...
gtk_binding_entry_remove(binding_set, /* GdkKey */ key, /*GdkModifierType*/ modifiers);
```

I wrote C# bindings for both functions, then used them to delete the following keybinds:

- Space
- KP_space
- Return
- ISO_Enter
- KP_Enter
- Ctrl+Shift+I
- Ctrl+Shift+D
- Arrow keys (and keypad arrows), with Ctrl and without
- Tab (and KP_tab), with Ctrl, Shift, or Ctrl+Shift

These are all of GTK's default keybindings. There's probably a more robust way to do this, but I didn't bother.